# Get status value with max function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table tblProcessStatus:

```
ProcessID  UnitID   Status
---------  ------   ------
1          1        DATA_APPROVED
2          2        DATA_APPROVED
3          2        FORM_APPROVED
```

one more table tblUnit:

```
UnitId   UnitName   Status
------   --------   ------
1        sometext1
2        sometext2
```

I need to update `Status` column in `tblUnit` with `Status` from `tblProcessStatus`. If `tblProcessStatus` has more than one row for same `UnitID`, then need to get `Status` which has `max(ProcessID)` to get the recent status.

Please help me with the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `apply`:

```
update u
    set status = ps.status
    from tblUnit u cross apply
         (select top (1) ps.*
          from tblProcessStatus ps
          where ps.UnitID = u.UnitID
          order by ps.ProcessID desc
         ) ps;
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try this

```
 update t set t.Status = tb.status from tblUnit as t inner join (
     select row_number() over (partition by unitid order by processid desc) as Slno, 
      processid, unitd, status
      from tblProcessStatus) as tb
 on t.unitid=tb.unitid and tb.slno=1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Update tblUnit set Status = b.Status From 
(Select Count(*)cnt,
        MAX(p.ProcessID) ProcessID, UnitID, p.Status From tblProcessStatus p ---where UnitID = 2
Group by UnitID, p.Status
)b,tblUnit un where un.unitid = b.unitid
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Update b set b.status=a.status
from (select max(processid) processid,min(unitid) unitid,status from  tblProcessStatus group by status) a join tblUnit b
on a.unitid=b.UnitID
```